# v center 6.5 Installation

Tags: vcenter

When trying to install v center 6.5 I received the following error :

> 1)Task failed on server: Module 'CPUID' power on failed
>
> 2)vim.fault.InvalidState
>
> 3)Installer log files are located at
>
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vcsaUiInstaller

Comment: Looks like a superuser.com/serverfault.com admin question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable VT-X in the Bios.
Sometimes it is also called Hyper-V. (For some obscure reason it often is hidden in the "security" section of the Bios.)

Most computers ship with the setting disabled by default. Some computers (especially laptops) are technically capable of VT-x but the Bios doesn't show it so you can't enable it.
In that case you are sheer out of luck.